# Ansible SHA1 encrypt variable

Tags: ansible, sha1, password-encryption

how can I encode a given string using ansible?

I'm trying to do this:

```
echo -n "mypassword" | sha1sum
```

Answer (score 4):

Q: **"*Encode a given string.*"**

A: Use [hash](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#encrypting-and-checksumming-strings-and-passwords) filter. For example, the command and the filter

```yaml
    - shell: echo -n "mypassword" | sha1sum
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
    - set_fact:
        pswd: "{{ 'mypassword' | hash('sha1') }}"
    - debug:
        var: pswd
```

give the same results

```yaml
    "result.stdout": "91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2  -"

    "pswd": "91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2"
```

---

Q: **"*Insert the output string into a file.*"**

A: For example, use the template

```yaml
shell> cat templates/pswd.j2.txt 
pswd: {{ pswd }}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: pswd.j2.txt
        dest: pswd.txt
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat pswd.txt 
pswd: 91dfd9ddb4198affc5c194cd8ce6d338fde470e2
```

Comment: And if I would insert the output string into a file?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open a new question if you have other issues.